# Extract all row values for a specific year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given the following Pandas dataframe, how to I extract only the data from 2019, which is 0.5 and 0.2? I am sorry if this is not enough information. I am new to pandas. I think the object I have is a Pandas.series object.

I am using python 3.

I am getting my data as such:

data = get_data()

This data comes from an external library

```
Date
2018-09-05    0.2
2019-05-10    0.5
2019-09-05    0.2
2020-05-12    0.5
2020-06-08    0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DatetimeIndex.year` to get the year # and compare:

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df.index).year == 2019]

2019-05-10    0.5
2019-09-05    0.2
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```

Or, as a list,

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df.index).year == 2019].tolist()
# [0.5, 0.2]
```

Comment: thanks this seems to work but I only want the value 0.5 and 0.2 and not the whole line

Comment: @user3702643 `df[pd.to_datetime(df.index).year == 2019].tolist()`?

Comment: @cs95 Is it possible to get rows between years using this same format? Ex. 2018-2019